# What is this diode and what is the use?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, diodes, circuit-design

I came through this schematic for powering a 3g module (SIM800L).
[image]

What is this diode connected with the bypass capacitors? By googling 5.1V 500mW I came to conclusion that it is probably a Zener diode(however the symbol does not seem like a zener diode) Is that true?
What is the use of it?

Comment: Quite simply overvoltage protection. If the input power goes above 5.1V the zener (you are correct) will clamp. Without any current limiting it might not survive very long, though.

Comment: so if Voltage increases above 5.1V, then current will not flow to what is connected to this circuit (the sim800L in that case) but it will be grounded through the zener diode. is that correct? like zener will "suck" everthing to the ground

Comment: @Not quite grounded. "Grounded" implies near 0V. More like the zener will break down and conduct in reverse causing it to be 5.1V across it which keeps everything else in parallel at 5.1V...as long as the zener survives.

Comment: so zener will "stabilise" the Voltage to 5.1 V incase that goes above 5.1V

Comment: Yeah. Or clamp, or limit.

Comment: All great stuff, except THAT IS NOT A SCHEMATIC SYMBOL FOR A ZENER DIODE.    Just sayin'

Comment: @KyleB  I already mentioned that and I said I came through this schematic. Means its not mine. calm your hormones down

Answer (score 3):

This is a Zener diode for over-voltage protection. Ordinarily, a diode conducts only in one direction. However, every diode has a "reverse breakdown" voltage, where the reverse bias voltage across the diode (or, the electric field across the PN junction) becomes great enough for the diode to start to conduct in the opposite direction.

Zener Diodes have finely tuned reverse breakdown voltages, and they can then be used to protect circuits from over-voltage by taking advantage of this reverse breakdown. If too much voltage is present, the Zener conducts in reverse bias. If designed properly, this will either (a) remove harmful voltage transients and allow the circuit to continue operating normally or (b) conduct enough current from the overvoltage source that a fuse blows, causing the system to fail safe.

Comment: isn't every diode working the same way? If I connect a regular diode reversed instead of zener with similar voltage 5.1V, wouldn't it work the same way?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but regular diodes are not optimized to work that way: imprecise breakdown, not designed to handle all the heat, far higher and fewer breakdown voltage selection etc

Comment: A general purpose diode usually has a reverse breakdown voltage that is very large, like 1kV, and that will not protect your circuit. You might be able to use any diode with a reverse breakdown of 5.1V, but there are more things to consider, such as the clamping voltage, peak and DC power rating, and failure mode. If you are not designing for any particular over-voltage case, you should get away with any Zener or TVS with 5.1V reverse breakdown voltage.

Comment: copy that, so principle is the same/similar, zener is the best option for this tho due to its charasteristics (low reverse breakdown etc)

Comment: Doing some research I found out that there should be a resistor in series with the Zener Diode. Why in this schematic the designer of the schematic did not use one? Not always required?

Comment: A Zener diode used for circuit protection should not have a series resistor. The resistor will make the Zener worse at protecting the circuit. Edit: There may be other applications of Zener diodes in forward bias that need a resistor to limit the current.